# Regretting Computer Science?

Tags: software-engineering

A message I sent to a CS professor:

So I have a question about computer science in general.

I would like to build "stuff" in the future, not just program my whole life. I'm not sure if I did right by majoring in Computer Science instead of an engineering field. I could always get my masters in Software Engineering but I was wondering, if I like to build "stuff" and watch it come to life, would computer science still be something I should major in?

Yes I like coding, but I would also like to build "stuff." By "stuff" I mean technology such as virtual reality goggles and so forth.

Can anyone answer this for me?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 parts of building "stuff". The physical components of the system and the behaviour of the system. To build the physical components of the system you need to learn about the physics and engineering but to implement complex behaviour of the system you need to learn computing. Basically any system behaviour can be implemented by connecting the parts of the system in a specific way (that's how machines before computing were built) but as the desired behaviour gets complex, the human mind cannot come up with the design using just connecting the part and that's were computing comes into picture.

For example: The VR goggles have a lot of physics and engineering involved but in the end all those components are measuring something aka input OR effecting something aka output and the software on these system is using these IO components and algorithms to derive the behaviour of the system.